# How do I limit SSH to only allow use with docker context?

Tags: docker, security, ssh

Since Docker supports SSH to connect to the daemon, I want to limit the shell the users use to only be executing what is needed for `docker context`.  But I tried /bin/false and /usr/bin/docker and neither worked correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `authorized_keys` of the user.  Add

`command="docker system dial-stdio"`  before the key e.g.

```
command="docker system dial-stdio" ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc...
```

This will limit the use to `docker context` only.  Except that if you try to login using SSH it somehow runs as an HTTP server.

```
$ ssh nosh@edge.xxx.com

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Connection: close

400 Bad RequestConnection to edge.xxx.com closed.
```

```
$ ssh nosh@edge.xxx.com
GET /_ping HTTP/1.0
Host: edge

HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Api-Version: 1.40
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Docker-Experimental: false
Ostype: linux
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Docker/19.03.6-ce (linux)
Date: Tue, 21 Jul 2020 19:54:59 GMT
Content-Length: 2
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

OKConnection to edge.xxx.com closed.
```

I'd rather somehow get rid of the HTTP server but at least it solves the primary problem.